# Message Template Token limitations

Tags: message-templates

We want to use Message Templates for tailoring our sponsorship renewal invoice reminders. We have multiple sponsorships setup as separate Membership Types with corresponding prices sets.  However data about "membership" is NOT available as tokens when using Message Templates. That data is available as Tokens when using  Schedule Reminders - but this means a separate Reminder is to be setup for each Membership Type. Question is why cannot Membership data (and for that matter Event data) be available as Tokens under Message Templates?

Comment: I would love to see the ability to assign normal Message Templates for the various Scheduled Reminders (membership and events). This is one reason I haven't used scheduled reminders: too much hassle to change every reminder for every event, and too risky that one would be missed.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackExchange Grant!

In regular messages token for other "entities" such as memberships, contributions or event registrations are not available because each contact can have any number of them.

For example, if a contact had two memberships or event registrations, CiviCRM would not know which data to "fill in" when sending the email.

This is why CiviCRM has several special functions such as event and membership reminders or thank you letters for contributions.

Comment: Thanks Fabian. Can you expand on the "several special functions" bit please - that could be very useful.

Comment: That's a big question ;) Maybe you want to start with having a look at Schedfuled remidner for events (https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/creating-an-event/#scheduled-reminders), renewal reminders for memberships (https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/scheduled-reminders/#renewal-reminders) and thanky you letters/mails for contributions (https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/manual-receipts-and-thank-yous/#thank-you-letters). Regards, Fabian

Answer (score 0):

Fuzion made an Extension that provides additional tokens that you should be able to use in this scenario. The [CiviToken extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/nzcofuzioncivitoken) includes

- Latest Memership Status
- Latest Membership Type
- Latest Current Membership Type etc

Comment: Great - will investigate that extension